# Wear OS foregroundService sleeps on API 30 update?

Tags: android, wear-os

I created a small wear os App based on API 28 that running on my galaxy watch 4.

Last week I got the new Galaxy Watch 4 update and it seems that google changed the foreground service conditions again -.-*

I created a foreground service that triggers a scheduled task each 30 seconds to send a request with okhttp2 to my server (heartbeat) and it works pretty fine with API level 28. After checking the heartbeat from server log it shows me the following :

```
20-02-2022 07:11:54 Heartbeat :fa9f65b0a96250bd  (virtual device android stuido)
20-02-2022 07:12:19 Heartbeat :My real watch id
20-02-2022 07:12:24 Heartbeat :fa9f65b0a96250bd
20-02-2022 07:12:54 Heartbeat :fa9f65b0a96250bd
20-02-2022 07:13:24 Heartbeat :fa9f65b0a96250bd
20-02-2022 07:13:54 Heartbeat :fa9f65b0a96250bd
20-02-2022 07:14:24 Heartbeat :fa9f65b0a96250bd
```

i would guess if the real watch switch to "standby" mode, it sets my foreground service to sleep until "wakeup". Does anybody got the same problem and got a solution to re-enable scheduled tasks in "standby" ? Are there any documentation for the new changes on the foregroundservice ?

Kind regards :)

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same on a Galaxy Watch4 but I cannot get it to work. As soon as the screen gets dark, my foreground service is stopped. I've just posted this a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71253130/is-it-possible-to-permanently-run-a-network-ping-service-reliably-in-wear-os

Comment: I think we have the same problem, here is an issue we created, if you could add something or tell them you have the same issue, you're welcome:
https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/228086086