# Is it possible to permanently run a network ping service reliably in Wear OS?

Tags: wear-os

I'm trying to find a way to run a network heartbeat service on Wear OS in a reliable way. The goal would be to have a process that is sending a network request every x minutes regardless of the state of the device (screen on/off, on charger, off charger, etc). Is it possible to achieve?

My approach was to run a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) with a [partial wake lock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK) that is rescheduling a new Runnable with postDelayed every x minutes. But when the watch is not on the charger, it stops running as soon as the screen gets dark.

This is the basic implementation of the foreground service:

```
public void onCreate() {
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread(TAG, Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();

    serviceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler(serviceLooper);

    tick();
}

private void tick() {
    submitDataViaNetwork();
    scheduleNextTick();
}

private void scheduleNextTick() {
    serviceHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            tick();
        }
    }, 60*1000);
}
```

Comment: Would work manager (>= 15 min) or AlarmManager work for this?  I think holding the wakelocks is a bad idea for performance and battery life here.

Comment: @YuriSchimke I need my tick to reliably run every 60 seconds. Of course it is drainig the battery, but that does not matter for my specific use case.

Comment: I think we have the same problem, here is an issue we created, if you could add something or tell them you have the same issue, you're welcome:
https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/228086086

Comment: @LukeB. I've taken it to Samsung support and they basically confirmed that it's not possible to keep it awake: "Samsung restricts foreground service to save more power from 3rd party applications".

Comment: A coworker of mine found something that seems to work, open the 'Wear' app on the smartphone connected to the watch and activate this:
Watch settings > Apps > your app > Allow background activity